# Can't modify Text Format

Tags: 7, users, input-formats

I am using Drupal 7.x and would like to start using [Pathologic](http://drupal.org/project/pathologic) to make sure that all of my relative links work properly.

As stated in their [instructions](http://drupal.org/node/257026), I need to configure my text formats to use Pathologic. When I try to save the configuration for a Text Format (or even create a new Text Format), it complains that I don't have permissions.

I have checked the permissions for my user and I have permission to "Administer text formats and filters". Anything else I should check?

Thanks,
Alan